# Batch-Script: Replace every "@" in file name with "_" in network drive including subfolders

Tags: batch-file, replace, directory, filenames

My Problem is this:

I want to replace every Special character such as "@" in file names.

Example:

old file: `test@home.txt`
new file: `test_home.txt`

This should be done in a special chosen Folder including subfolders. The user should easily Change the Location (Folder).

Well, I will give this a try, but I am not sure how to:

```
%PATH% = G:\Tests\Folder

::Replace '@' with '_'
   SET _test=test@file.txt   
   SET _result=%_test:_=file
   ECHO %_result%          =test_file
```

Comment: Read http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html and http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set`syntax for replacing a string:

```
set "var1=my old hat"
set "var2=%var1:old=new%"
echo %var1% was better than %var2%
```

To get all txt-files:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%i
  rem substitution does not work with special %%i variable type
  set "oldname=%%i"
  set "newname=!oldname:@=_!"
  echo rename "!oldname!" "!newname!"
)
```

Why `!` instead of `%`?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)